# AWS Glue pySpark Truncate table from database PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)



AmazonS3_node1673448010093 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={
        "quoteChar": '-1',
        "withHeader": True,
        "separator": ";",
        "optimizePerformance": False,
    },
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={
        "paths": ["s3://folder/data.csv"],
        "recurse": True,
    },
    transformation_ctx="AmazonS3_node1673448010093"
)


AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1673448012790 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    frame=AmazonS3_node1673448010093,
    database="database",
    table_name="table",
    transformation_ctx="AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1673448012790",
)


job.commit()
```

I am creating a job in glue that reads some data from an object uploaded to S3, reads the file and saves the records in a database, the problem I have is that the database already has previous records and I need to replace all the data How could I delete all the records in the database before writing?